# Firefox - Developer Tools display XHR parameters

Tags: firefox, parameters, xmlhttprequest, firefox-developer-tools

I am using the Firefox Developer Tools for debugging ajax request.
This tools works perfectly for me, but today Firefox update to the 71 version, and there is something different for the display of XHR parameters (query string).

Before, the parameters were displayed like this (Firefox 70): 
**param1** = value1 
**param2** = value2 
....
[image: Version 70]

But now, they are displayed like this (Firefox 71): 
&param1=value1&param2=value2....
[image: Version 71]

Is not really a big problem, but when there is many parameters the reading become really difficult.
Firebug users have you experienced the same issue ? 
And is there a way to display the parameters like before ?

Thanks !

Comment: Firebug was **discontinued** in 2017! Stop using it. Upgrade to the latest version of Firefox and use the built-in Developer Tools instead.

Comment: Yes of course, I am using the built-in Developer Tools. My question was not enough accurate.

Comment: You should completely remove Firebug from your question to avoid confusion because it's unrelated. Also, maybe you could post a screenshot of what you're seeing and tell which version of Firefox you're using. I just had a look at some GET requests in Firefox 71 - 73 (Nightly) and they are displayed separately within the *Params* tab.

Comment: This is one of the few times where a screenshot would help let us know what your issue is. Personally, I see both a URL with parameters formatted as they are in the URL, and parameters listed like you first mention. So, this question is going to need more information for us to know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I have upadted my question. Also the parameters are displayed also on the firefox developper edition version 72.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Firefox 71, which already got reported as [bug 1605172](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1605172) and got fixed in Firefox 73.

As a workaround, instead of checking the POST parameters in the console, you can have a look at them in the [*Network* panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor). Just select the request and switch to the *Params* tab. In there you'll see both the formatted output and the payload as it got sent over the wire.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will use the network pannel until the bug will be corrected.

Comment: Tremendous. I've been wondering if this has been bugging others, too.

Comment: Quick update, the Mozilla people reacted quickly and already fixed it now for Firefox 73. I've updated my answer accordingly.